# Force cloudant replication start

Tags: python, couchdb, cloudant

im using cloudant and i created a base database containing all my views/filters etc... and i everytime that i create a new database, i create a new replication from this "custom_docs" to "new_created_database", but i need to use this filters, soon as possible after the database is created but the cloudant replication take a cycle(about 30 seconds) to start replication, is there any way to FORCE IT TO START AFTER CREATED?

```
from cloudant.replicator import Replicator

    if db_name not in client.all_dbs():
        client.create_database(db_name)

        # Create replicate to get filters, views and map reducers from custom_docs database
        Replicator(client).create_replication(
            source_db=client['custom_docs'],
            target_db=client[db_name],
            continuous=True
        )
```

that the code that i create, but there is not "start" or "force start" way

Comment: Not that I know of. Is there a particular reason why your application can't create the desired artifacts (e.g. design docs) instead of using replication? On a side note your code indicates that you are setting up continuous replication instead of one-time replication. Is it your intention to permanently keep the newly created database(s) in sync with the custom_docs database?

Comment: @ptitzler yes i need, cuz in this custom_docs im going to create the filters (generic) and views that will be replicated to all others databases, if i create the artifact at the time of database creation if i need to change the filter or create a new one, now i need to iterate over dbs and add documents for each db, if i delete, i must delete in each database. Using the custom_docs i just change in this database and it will be replicated to all the others, understand? if i could "duplicate" documents from custom_docs without waiting the replication startup, would help too